# Change wwwroot/images folder in (Development, Production)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a `wwwroot` folder structure

[image]

In the development environment, I am using `src/*` folder
and in production environment I am using (`css/`, `fonts/`, `images/`, `js/`)

The problem is in src images only

```
 <img src="~/images/logo.png" alt="" />
```

What is the best way to change the src image?

in the development environment, I am using `~/src/images/logo.png`

and production environment I am using `~/images/logo.png`

Comment: You can use: `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images", file.FileName);` where file is of form `IFormFile`

Comment: store the paths in `appsettings.development.json` file for dev environment and `appsettings.json` file for prod respectively, asp.net core will automatically switch between them based on the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Razor view, you could access the environment by `@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env` like

1. Add reference to the csthml file

   ```
   @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
   ```
2. Add image src.

   ```
   @if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       <img src="~/src/images/logo.png" alt="" />
   }
   else
   {
       <img src="~/images/logo.png" alt="" />
   }
   ```